# Does Android NDK support "-z execstack" flag?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm tring to build a executable with android ndk to test shellcode. I set 'LOCAL_CFLAGS := -z execstack' to make the stack executable but it does not work. Doesn't android ndk support '-z execstack' option?

Here's the code:

18 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 19 LOCAL_MODULE := shellcode-test
 20 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/shellcode-test.c
 21 LOCAL_CFLAGS := -z execstack -Wl,--execstack

Check result: only 'RW', no 'E'

$ aarch64-linux-gnu-readelf -l shellcode-test
...
GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Android NDK forces noexecstack options when build executables or libraries. So '-z execstack' in my Android.mk is overridden by NDK's default option:

`./build/core/build-binary.mk:LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wa,--noexecstack
./build/core/build-binary.mk:LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-z,noexecstack`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get your code to compile with an executable stack, the platform won't load it as executable. Executable stacks are a big security risk.